# How to open '.flh' file?

Tags: windows-10, file-extension

I have an animation (gif) in a `.flh` extension. It's being used by a game I'm rebuilding.

Unfortunately, I cannot find any way to open it. I tried VLC Media Player and Gimp and was looking for a software as well, but didn't find anything. I'm on Windows 10.

It appears it's an `FLIC Animation` file, but I'm not sure. **How to open it?**

[INTO.FLH](http://www90.zippyshare.com/v/Sxs0dTZf/file.html) and a [Virus scan](https://www.virustotal.com/pl/file/dcf62e58eaf5b1be4928ef104269af772674e9876df4e871b474ba4f20c34120/analysis/1490895853/)

Comment: Sounds like you will have to create your own tool to open it.

Comment: @Ramhound not good. I don't even have any documentation about it. It's just being used by a really old game. Is there a way of opening invalid files, for me to start somewhere from?

Comment: Read [What is File Extension FLH?](http://www.solvusoft.com/en/file-extensions/file-extension-flh/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll find everything you need on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FLIC_(file_format))

From there, I found out that there is an [open source reader](https://github.com/aseprite/flic)